# Dynamic minimum date on Wordpress / Elementor

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, forms, elementor

i'm building my website by myself for the first time.
This will be a classic Wordpress portfolio website with an Elementor Pro contact form.
There is something I would really like to do: putting a dynamic minimum date for work booking. Explaining better: in my date tab, I would like to "grey out" seven days starting from today, then no maximum date. Is that possible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is that a regular date input field? Please add some code and try to be more accurate.

Comment: Hi, it's an Elementor date field, which lets me set a minimum fixed date and a maximum fixed date with "Native HTML5" toggle activated. Here's a [screenshot](https://ibb.co/GPmyctG) of the settings, hope that helps.

Comment: [Another screen](https://ibb.co/BgqCJ11) explaining what I would like to do practically.

Comment: I see many people asked same or similar questions... as [here](https://github.com/elementor/elementor/issues/6372). You can see some solutions in there, but maybe look at [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/368713/min-and-max-date-with-date-format-in-elementor-form-not-working) ... seems easy to understand.